# Can I use a command to make Dispensers quiet?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have an automatic sorting system that uses minecarts and dispensers which is giving me a headache. I tried putting the carpet block on top of it (treating it like a note block) to see if it would muffle it. Nothing. I'm wondering if there is a command I could use to quiet it.

Comment: Don't think it can be done :( Your best bet is probably just turning off the contraption when there are no items in the dispensers (they make less noise when they're actually dispensing something). Or just turn off block sounds and turn on subtitles instead

Comment: If you're willing to use resource packs, a common suggestion on other forums seems to be Quiet Dispensers and Droppers from [Vanilla Tweaks](https://vanillatweaks.net/picker/resource-packs/). In vanilla, I think the only way is to move it more than 16 blocks away from the player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe there is a command that muffles noise. However, you could use comparators to only fire when the dispenser has an item in it.

dispenser > comparator > redstone wire (1) > repeater(1-tick) > wire > dispenser

This will cause the dispenser to fire only when it has an item in it. Note that this method will not work if you have more than one hopper flowing into the dispenser as it will fill faster than it fires, and the comparator will provide a constant signal, stopping item flow.